# Низкая скорость google drive api

Tags: c#, .net, api, сеть, google-drive

Когда я загружаю файл с помощью Google .NET API, скорость загрузки не превышает 2 МБ/с, с чем это может быть связано и как это исправить?

Мой код авторизации и загрузки

```
public async Task AuthorizeAsync()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Credentials)))
        {
            var certificate = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(Properties.Resources.Lastrium_games_Cert, "notasecret", System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
            Credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(ServiceAccountEmail) { Scopes = Scopes }.FromCertificate(certificate));
        }

        Service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = Credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });
    });
}

public async Task<Google.Apis.Download.IDownloadProgress> DownloadFileAsync(string fileId, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var getRequest = Service.Files.Get(fileId);
    getRequest.MediaDownloader.ChunkSize = ChunkSize;

    getRequest.MediaDownloader.ProgressChanged += ProgressChanged;

    Google.Apis.Download.IDownloadProgress progresser = null;
    try
    {
        progresser = await getRequest.DownloadAsync(stream, cancellationToken);
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {

    }

    getRequest.MediaDownloader.ProgressChanged -= ProgressChanged;

    return progresser;
}
```

Даже если использовать официальный пример и делать в точности как там, скорость та же.

P.S. если вдруг зависит я подключаю сервисный аккаунт Гугл (если есть другой способ доступа к одному гугл диску было бы очень хорошо)

Answer (score 0):

1. Мб само ограничение с их стороны.
2. Покажите Ping до url с вашими данными login:pass@url (данные можете скрыть. Интересует проброс)
3. Попробуйте несколько параллельных запросов

Comment: 1. Ограничения нету, так как у других все нормально (может дело в сервисном аккаунте)

2. Каким образом я могу это сделать?

3. Даже если делать несколько запросов, каждый будет увеличивать максимальную скорость на 2МБ/с, то есть если у пользователя скорость соединения около 500МБ/с, то надо сделать не менее 500 запросов, что конечно как я думаю сильно повлияет на производительность